# virtual machines virtualbox disappear

Tags: virtualbox

Today I opened my VB and discovered that all of my seven VM have disappeared.

I tried to import one old VM but I saw that error message:

```
Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\michele\VirtualBox VMs\Magento Ultimo\Magento Ultimo-disk1_2.vmdk'.
VMDK: could not create new file 'C:\Users\michele\VirtualBox VMs\Magento Ultimo/Magento Ultimo-disk1_2.vmdk' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS).


Result Code: 
VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: 
ApplianceWrap
Interface: 
IAppliance {8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e}
```

I am using Windows 10 64 bit .... may someone help me?

Thanks.

PS: I am not an IT expert so I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: Should this be in server-fault?

Answer (score 10):

Ok solved... Inside the UI of VirtualBox i clicked *Machines>add* .... however it's very strange that they disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

launch Oracle Virtualbox as admin and you will see all created VM's. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know that the case is resolved, but I want to add why it occurs. It happens when you install Virtual Box and machines as admin, and later run VB as normal user (or just different user). The program by default looks for machines in the given user folder.